# XSL-FO overflows width when flowing from page-master with wide region-body to narrow (including column-width changes) in Apache FOP and XMLSpy

Tags: width, xsl-fo, apache-fop, column-width

I'm using XSL-FO (Formatting Objects) in XMLSpy with Apache FOP.

When I flow content from a first page having a simple-page-master with a wide region-body onto a second (rest) page having a narrow region-body, the content on the second page has the same width as the content on the first page, overflowing the body.  This also happens if I set the column-count on the second page to be greater than the column-count on the first page.

How do I force the engine to recognize that the available horizontal space has been decreased, and adjust the body (or column) width accordingly?

An example of the problem can be seen here (use with any XML document that contains sufficient text content to flow from page 1 to page 2):

http://pastebin.com/VGyWYNBS

Comment: I've noticed now that the problem only seems to be on the first that uses the "rest" page master; the content on the third page of the output (second page to use the second master) seems to fit the columns/margins correctly.

Comment: Further investigation reveals that SOMETIMES it is only on the first page and other times it continues.  It might be that a break-before or break-after directive corrects the problem, but I have not confirmed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this to Apache using Bugzilla:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50794

Chris Bowditch posted this response there:

> the problem you describe is known as
>   Changing IPD problem. That is a known
>   issue in 0.95. For v1.0 we developed a
>   fix for it that works in most cases.
>   There are some limitations related to
>   lists and tables, but for regular
>   text, upgrading to FOP v1.0 should
>   resolve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

filling in with randome text, your xsl-fo works well with a commercial formatter,
one column first page, three on the second and third pages?

Comment: I suppose that confirms that the problem is with Apache FOP and not with XSL-FO in general.  Which commercial formatter did you use?  Do you know a work-around that's compatible with FOP?